# p.474 of Wade's Introduction to Analysis (4th edition)

Tags: general-topology, analysis

On Wade p.474 the statement (ii) of Theorem 12.29 is: "Suppose that $V$ is an [bounded?] open set in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\overline E \subset V$, and that $\phi: V \to \mathbb R^n$ is $1-1$ and $\phi^{-1}$ is $C^1$ on $\phi(V)$ with $\Delta_{\phi^{-1}} \neq 0.$ If $f$ is integrable on $\phi(E)$, then $f \circ \phi$ is integrable on $E$".

I would like to ask questions about the lines 4~6 of the proof of (ii): "Set $\psi = \phi^{-1}$ and apply (2) [ on p.457 in the course of the proof of Lemma 12.9] with $\psi$ in place of $\phi$, to choose an absolute constant $C$ and cubes ${Q_k}^{\psi}$ such that $\psi(Q_k) \subseteq {Q_k}^{\psi}$ and $|{Q_k}^{\psi}| \le C|Q^k|$."

[Question 1] In order to apply (2) with $\psi$ in place of $\phi$, I think we should first show that, in the function $\psi:\phi(V) \to V$, $\phi(V)$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb R^n$. How can this be shown?

[Qustion 2] ln place of $\overline E \subset V$ in the statement of Lemma 12.9, what ($ \overline {\phi(E)} \subset \phi(V)$ ?) should we use in order to deduce that there is an $M \gt 0$ such that $\left \Vert \psi(x)-\psi(y) \right \Vert \le M \left\Vert x-y \right\Vert$,  for$x,y \in Q_k$, which corresponds to (2) of p.457?